# Python Invoke and console output issue

Tags: python, invoke, pyinvoke

I am using [Invoke](http://invoke.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for task execution. The problem is, it hides most of the console output. Because of which I cannot see output from my app.

I have a task that runs a shell. Invoke changes the behavior of default shell. `Back key` does not work.

What can I do to get most of the outputs from console?
Also what is the better way to execute shell, so that the shell has all there features it is supposed to have?

## update

Below is the content from my `tasks.py`

```
from invoke import task, run

@task
def serve():
    run("python manage.py runserver")

@task
def test():
    run("python manage.py test")

@task
def shell():
    run("python manage.py shell")
```

Comment: I presume you're using Windows? I'm having the same issue on Windows, on Ubuntu this works fine.

Comment: @KarolisŠarapnickis No, i am using Mint 15, which is as u know Ubuntu's variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing `pty=True` to `run` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried with the `--pty (-p)` flag and `--debug (-d)` flag:

`invoke -pd task-name`